# Verificar se os valores de uma coluna de um certo DataFrame existe em uma determinada lista utilizando np.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Olá! Estive tentando verificar se um certo valor presente numa coluna de um certo dataframe está presente
em uma lista, utilizando o np.where.

Em outras palavras, isso ficaria assim:

```
 df = {
    'Pais': ['Brazil', 'Colombia', 'Argentina', 'EUA'],
    'PIB' : [1000, 1056, 1070, 410]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

america_do_sul = ['Brazil', 'Colombia', 'Argentina', 'Peru', 'Venezuela', 'Ecuador', 'Bolivia', 'Paraguay', 'Uruguay']
df['Sulamericano'] = np.where(df['Pais'] in america_do_sul, 1, 0)
```

A idéia do código é criar uma coluna no meu dataframe chama 'Sulamericano'onde tem o valor '1' para sim e 
'0' para não.

Porém, quando este código é executado gera o seguinte erro:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Observação: Os valores contidos na coluna PIB são fictícios!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta alterar a forma de comparação com a lista.

Coloca assim:

```
df['Sulamericano'] = np.where(np.isin(df['Pais'], america_do_sul), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sei que você pediu para utilizar `np.where`, mas aqui está uma solução que usa uma sintaxe um pouco mais legível, na minha opinião:

```
df['Sulamericano'] = df['Pais'].isin(america_do_sul).astype(int)
```